# Prove every irreducible polynomial over a field of characteristic of $0$ is separable.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove that every irreducible polynomial over a field of characteristic of $0$ is separable.

I found the proof was actually not too hard.
Suppose $f(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible of degree $n$, then the only constant factors of $f(x)$ are $1$ and $f(x)$ up to constant, then $Df(x)$ and $f(x)$ shares no common factors, hence they can't have any common zeros. Therefore, $f(x)$ must have distinct zeros.

But my questions is, it seems like I did not use the assumption that the characteristic of $F$ is $0$ in my proof or maybe I used this assumption implicitly but I did not notice.

Can anyone tells me where did I used the assumption that $F$ has to have a characteristic $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the characteristic is not zero, $Df$ can be zero ( consider  $Df$ where $f=X^p-a$, $p$ is the characteristic), and every element is a root of $Df$.